# What is the function of [^] (caret in square brackets) at the end of a dialog box input line in Midnight Commander?

Tags: midnight-commander

```
 ┌───────────────────── Select ──────────────────────┐ 
 │ ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛ [^] <===== THIS 
 │ [ ] Files only           [x] Case sensitive       │ 
 │ [x] Using shell patterns                          │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Originally I wanted to phrase the question as "how to activate this" (as I assumed it would provide the previous entries to the same dialog), but after googling for a while it seems as if it has no functionality because no tutorial ever mentions it...

Comment: I assume it means sorted in ascending order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the history (of entries, previously visited directories, etc.).

#### 1. On the top bar

```
  Left     File     Command     Options     Right                                 
┌<─ ~ ───────────────────────────────.[^]>┐┌<─ ~ ───────────────────────────.[^]>┐
│.n    Name          │ Size  │Modify time ││.n    Name      │ Size  │Modify time │
│/..                 │UP--DIR│Jun 19 19:44││/..             │UP--DIR│Jun 19 19:44│
```

The `[^]` above the panes are the directory history; either click on it or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

#### 2. At the end of the command line at the bottom (if enabled)

```
├─────────────────────────────────┤├──────────────────────────────────────┤
│UP--DIR                          ││UP--DIR                               │
└─────────────── 141G/276G (51%) ─┘└──────────────────── 141G/276G (51%) ─┘
0 [02:02:02]                                                            [^]
 1Help  2Menu  3View  4Edit  5Copy  6RenMov  7Mkdir 8Delete  9PullDn 10Quit
```

Here it is the command line history; click on it or hit or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

#### 3. On any dialog box input line

Such as the one in the <kbd>+</kbd> selection dialog, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> rename tool, etc. To activate it, click on it or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

**Source:** In `man mc`, case-insensitively search for `alt-h`. Besides, have this quote:

```
Alt-<chr>
       means hold the Meta or Alt key down while typing <chr>.  If
       there is no Meta or Alt key, type ESC, release it, then type the
       character <chr>.
```

Finally, [if Alt does not work for you and you use Xterm](https://askubuntu.com/q/442644).

Comment: Thanks for adding the "Final remark" part because `Alt`+`h` has never worked for me, only `Esc`+`h`, and I've been using MC on 3 different distros and on remote shells with default settings.

Comment: @toraritte You are welcome. If you use Xterm, check the link I have added.